# How to detect requested urls in Javascript or Python

Tags: javascript, python, request, network-programming

I would like to know whether there's a javascript or python package that could help monitor the requests performed by an application. Let's say for example in my browser I click on a document. The package should be able to grab the requested link for that document. I know packet analysis can be done with wireshark but in this case I would like to have a javascript or python package to monitor and hopefully save in a txt file all the links accessed by a user while browsing the internet

Comment: Python's mitmproxy can do that if you set it up

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build your own program to perform this kind tasks.
In Pyhton you can use mitmproxy which will start proxy server.Then you can use it to intercept the websites.